# Android Studio, how to change left side panel font size in Material Theme

Tags: android-studio

because of my bad searching skills, I have been searching for 2 hours and haven't found it

After I install Material Theme from Plugin, I want to change the font size of this left panel How can I do it?

Not the part of typing code. I want to increase the font size of the file name where the files are listed. The panel on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to increase the font size of the android studio left panel where project files are? If you want to do that you can do it like this:

Go to `File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance` (or you can press Ctrl + Alt + S and go to `Appearance & Behaviour > Appearance`), and there you will have to check `Use custom font:` and you can select a custom font and font size.

[image]

Comment: I've done it several times already, But I did it again as you suggested. I do not know the reason. Suddenly it works. Perhaps I made a mistake. Thank you very much

Comment: Lastly, Do you know how to increase the font size of the opend files name at the top line? if you don\`t know you don\`t have to answer it

Comment: I think that when you change the font size as I described in my answer it will change the size of the file tabs too. @rounpaleum